# Nuxt.js: can't generate routes

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I want to generate both static routes (`/contact`, `/about`, ...) and dynamic routes (`/project/1`, `/project/2,` ...) for my project, so that when user refreshes the page while visiting any of these routes, the page still works.

But when doing `npm run generate` I only get `Generated route "/"` and in `/dist` folder I see no routes generated.

Nuxt.js version used: `2.14.7`

I tried with both `universal` and `spa` modes, it works with neither.

In nuxt.config.js I have at the top:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const dynamicRoutes = async () => {
  const routes = await axios.get('http://my-project.com/wp/wp-json/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(res => res.data.map((project) => `/project/${project.ID}/${project.post_name}`))
    .then(res => res.concat(
      [
        '/about',
        '/contact',
        '/portfolio'
      ]
    ))
  return routes
}
```

Then in `export default {}`:

```js
generate: {
  routes: dynamicRoutes
},
```

Comment: I cloned the project on my own machine and it generate the routes in the dist folder

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim any idea why Nuxt fails to generate any route on my machine when running `npm run generate`?

Comment: could you show a screenshot after running the command?

Comment: i use such issue to generate sitemap on nuxt.js
in nuxt.config.js
add to module 
 '@nuxtjs/sitemap'
and then add sitemap 
  sitemap: {
    routes () {
      return axios.post(process.env.APP_URL+'/sitemap')
      .then(
        res =>
        res.data.map(link =>  link)
      )
    }
  },
i think you can use same behave

Comment: @drake035 you gotta remove the nuxt router module and fix the file structure - https://gist.github.com/MexsonFernandes/d04495c86b115bbe29f26b36b0b35d2d#gistcomment-3555332. I have cloned and checked...its working  flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.mode='hash'` seems to be incompatible with `generate.routes` config. When `router.mode` is set to `hash`, the Nuxt generator [ignores `generate.routes` and only creates a single route for `/`](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/b80056c/packages/generator/src/generator.js#L123-L124), presumably because only the landing page is expected to exist in `hash` mode (i.e., `index.html` sets up a router, which handles all routing for the app).

That hash mode is also in conflict with [the mode set in `router.js`](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/fabricepallaud.com/blob/60090b7/router.js#L16), but if you really needed hash routing, you should opt to set it only in `router.js` to allow `generate.routes` to be processed.

Also note `mode='universal'` is equivalent to `ssr=true`, so the [`ssr=false` config](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/fabricepallaud.com/blob/c30ec29/nuxt.config.js#L17-L18) does not make sense alongside that mode. If generating a static site, you want `ssr=true` so that any `asyncData()` and `fetch()` hooks are invoked to populate your static page data. This setting also obviates the need to append [`/about`, `/contact`, and `/portfolio` in `dynamicRoutes()`](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/fabricepallaud.com/blob/c30ec29/nuxt.config.js#L6-L12), as they would already be included in the generated routes.

[GitHub PR](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/fabricepallaud.com/pull/10)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have to add `mode: 'universal'` in config. Add `target: 'static'` to simplify it. Read more - https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/deployment-targets/. With `ssr: true` you will get full static mode website with relevant hooks as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208463/8153537.

Next, you can remove @nuxt/router module. Check my gist - https://gist.github.com/MexsonFernandes/d04495c86b115bbe29f26b36b0b35d2d. Nuxt would generate all the required routes as per the folder structure. So there is no need for extra config.

Check this gist for project page route - https://gist.github.com/MexsonFernandes/d04495c86b115bbe29f26b36b0b35d2d#gistcomment-3555332.

Comment: Thank you :) But @tony19's slighltly earlier answer already solved my issue (`target: 'static'` doesn't seem required btw)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code please ?

```
generate: {
 async routes(){
   const routes = await axios.get('http://my-project.com/wp/wp-json/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(res => res.data.map((project) => `/project/${project.ID}/${project.post_name}`))
    return [...routes,
      [
        '/about',
        '/contact',
        '/portfolio'
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but same result I'm afraid.

Comment: Could you log: the response from axios, create an array of the return, log it, then return the array and show use the directory structure as Brahim said

Comment: Axios response: `["/project/14/test", "/project/16/16", "/project/17/17"`. About `/pages` directory structure: I have `about.vue`, `contact.vue` etc at the root of this directory, and also a its root I have a `/projects` folder in which there is a `_id.vue` file and a `/slug` directory.